# How can I make a custom shell?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, macos

I want to have a custom shell in my IDE (like having multiple `.profile` files). It is only configurable to a single execution, and it's currently set to `/bin/bash`.  I want to set up the environment before the shell, so that every shell that opens in the IDE has the environment set up.  How can I do this?

I have tried creating a file with the following lines.

```
echo setting path
PG_BIN=/Users/user/Documents/pg/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$PG_BIN

echo git prompt
. ~/.bin/git-prompt.sh
```

When I try to execute it, it just fails because, when the script finishes, the terminal window doesn't remain open, and I cannot interact with it when the script ends. I can't use a script to set up the environment variables and get an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three ways to accomplish this.

1. Running `bash --rcfile mycustomrc` will read whatever customizations you need from the given file; season with `--login` or `--noprofile` to taste, depending on whether you do or do not want the `mycustomrc` to mix with the standard shell settings.
2. Act on a particular environment setting to determine whether or not to load the custom settings in the standard shell settings files. That is, in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, place the custom code within `if [[ $FOO_IDE -eq 1 ]]; then ... fi`. The IDE would need to set this environment variable, or may already set some suitable env var to act on. Perhaps better if you want all your shell configs in the usual files, and not scattered hither and yon.
3. Feed the custom shell configuration into a new `bash` process, then interact with it. See e.g. [`feed`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/feed), [`feed.1`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/feed.1), [`zcomppoke`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/filesys/zcomppoke), [`zcomppoke.1`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/filesys/zcomppoke.1) for this pattern in action. More complicated, but does populate the history, and does support things that are less able to perform the previous two sorts of customizations.

Comment: Thank you!  I went with #1, because it was very quick.  But I am going to go with #2 asap.  That seems perfect for this, and it means I can use it in the normal terminal, so I can have the same env in both!  This is perfect.  Thank you!